# October CMS - DynamicPDF plugin fails

Tags: octobercms

I've installed the DynamicPDf plugin by Renatio in order to generate PDF as attachment
in emails.
But I can't get it to work.

```
use Renatio\DynamicPDF\Classes\PDF; // import facade

  ...

$temp_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'inv');
PDF::loadTemplate('renatio::invoice')->save($temp_file);

Mail::send('acme.blog::mail.welcome', $data, function ($message) {
    $message->attach($temp_file, ['as' => 'Your_Invoice.pdf']);
});
```

I keep getting the same error

> No query results for model [Renatio\DynamicPDF\Models\Template]

Can someone help me ?

Update // Here's my code

```
<?php namespace Codalia\Membership\Helpers;

use October\Rain\Support\Traits\Singleton;
use Renatio\DynamicPDF\Classes\PDF; // import facade
use Codalia\Membership\Models\Member;

   ...

class EmailHelper
{
    use Singleton;

   ...

    public function payment($recordId, $data)
    {
        $member = Member::find($recordId);
        $vars = ['first_name' => $member->first_name,
                 'last_name' => $member->last_name,
                 'amount' => $data['amount'],
                 'item' => $data['item'],
                 'payment_mode' => $data['mode'],
        ];

        $temp_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'inv');
        PDF::loadTemplate('renatio::invoice-membership', $vars)->save($temp_file);

        Mail::send('codalia.membership::mail.payment_email, $vars, function($message) use($member, $temp_file) {
            $message->to($member->email, 'Admin System');
            $message->subject(Lang::get('codalia.membership::lang.email.payment_subject));
            $message->attach($temp_file, ['as' => 'Your_Invoice.pdf']);
        });
      }

   ...

}
```

Comment: hmm can you please check that template is exist `renatio::invoice`

Comment: I created it in the back office, so I guess it exists.

Comment: can you share a screenshot where you created it because I checked, and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got it.

```
    $vars = ['amount' => 1.00, 'item' => 'stuff'];
    $temp_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'inv');
    PDF::loadTemplate('invoice-membership', $vars)->save($temp_file);
```

The `renatio::` part is useless here as it refers to a template as a file (ie: PDF views). Since I create my templates in the backoffice (ie: PDF templates), all data is stored in database.
But I have to say that the official documentation is poorly documented regarding this point.
They should be more specific about how to use the methods with the PDF templates.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass $temp_file to the function to be able to use it

```php
    Mail::send('acme.blog::mail.welcome', $data, function ($message) use($temp_file) {
        $message->attach($temp_file, ['as' => 'Your_Invoice.pdf']);
    });
```

EDIT :
I add the same need for my website.
So i've created a class inside my plugin to generate PDFs for Invoices, voucher or tickets and it seems to be the same as you.

```php
    <?php namespace LucasPalomba\Tranfers\Classes;
    
        use Flash;
        use Request;
        use LucasPalomba\Tranfers\Models\Settings;
        use Carbon\Carbon;
        use Renatio\DynamicPDF\Classes\PDF;
    
    
    class GeneratePDF {
        
        ...
    
        public static function invoice($dossier) {
    
            $price_without_taxes = number_format( ($dossier->prix_a_regler * 100 / 110) ,'2');
    
            $PDF = [
                'nom' => $dossier->client->nom,
                'prenom' => $dossier->client->prenom,
                'adresse' => $dossier->client->adresse,
                'code_postal' => $dossier->client->code_postal,
                'ville' => $dossier->client->ville,
                'email' => $dossier->client->email,
                'reference' => $dossier->reference,
                'price_without_taxes' => $price_without_taxes,
                'vat_amount' => $dossier->prix_a_regler - $price_without_taxes,
                'prix_a_regler' => $dossier->prix_a_regler
            ];
            $invoice = (strtolower($dossier->client->langue_site) == 'fr')? 'renatio::invoice_fr': 'renatio::invoice' ;
            $temp_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'inv');
            PDF::loadTemplate($invoice, (array)$PDF)
                ->save($temp_file);
    
            $filename = 'invoice-' . trim($dossier->reference);
            $output = PDF::loadTemplate($invoice, (array)$PDF)->output();
            $filepath = temp_path() . '/' . $filename . '.pdf';
            \File::put( $filepath, $output);
    
            $file = new \System\Models\File;
            $file->data = $filepath;
            $file->is_public = true;
            $file->save();
            
            $dossier->pdf()->add($file);
    
            return $temp_file;
    
    
        }
```

Then in my plugin, i call the class like this to get the PDF and attach it to a mail :

```php
    ...
    $invoice = GeneratePDF::invoice($dossier);
    
    Mail::send('lucaspalomba.tranfers::mail.'.$view , $vars , function($message) use ($dossier, $invoice){
    
            $message->attach($quote , ['as' => 'Your_Quote.pdf']);
            $message->to($dossier->client->email); //#0003
    
        });
    ...
```

Are you sure you have created the template `renatio::invoice-membership` in the backoffice ?

Best,

Comment: Sure. I've just added it at the bottom of my post.

Comment: i add some part of my plugin too to help you, As i asked , are you sure you have created the template in your backoffice ?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I finally found out what was the problem. You can check it out in my answer above.